# Can men watch sport competitions of women via TV?

Tags: sunnah, men, non-mahram, tv

I was wondering if it is permissible for men to watch the sport competitions which their players are women. (**Note**: I said that because of the cover of the women in different sport competitions. Since as almost everybody know, commonly they have not Islamic veil or hijab and even appropriate Islamic clothes ...). Hence, I would know if would it be permissible to see them in Sport situation or not?

Answer (score 1):

First to answer your question, you need to know the following: What is the Awra `عوره`?

That is a whole topic on its own and answers ranges from the Niqab to the no Hijab to the privates based on different interruptions of the Sunnah and Ayat.

If you have your answer for that and feel confident about it, gaze your eyes to the following Ayah:

> قُلْ لِلْمُؤْمِنِينَ يَغُضُّوا مِنْ أَبْصَارِهِمْ وَيَحْفَظُوا فُرُوجَهُمْ ذَلِكَ أَزْكَى لَهُمْ إِنَّ اللَّهَ خَبِيرٌ بِمَا يَصْنَعُونَ * وَقُلْ لِلْمُؤْمِنَاتِ يَغْضُضْنَ مِنْ أَبْصَارِهِنَّ وَيَحْفَظْنَ فُرُوجَهُنَّ
>
> Tell the believers (men/women) to cover their sight and protect their privates that is better for them for Allah knows what they do.

So if you have your answer to what the Awra is that is what you are allowed to watch on TV if it is covered. Awra that you accept for your wife/sister/daughter and mother.